# Vista previa de archivo de excel con Iframe

Tags: iframe

¿Es posible cargar una vista previa de un archivo excel seleccionado con el botón tipo "file" y dentro de un iframe?

Con esta línea lo logro pero el archivo tiene que estar previamente subido a un servidor, y yo necesito que sea desde un botón donde el usuario suba su archivo:

```
<iframe style = float:right src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR_qMnlJXJRuuHuq6czogRAVeWGpTDtChpvcY-vpd8NUi6PqUQIOAorS0rk4F028A/pubhtml?gid=25008624&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=true" width="350" height="350" >
</iframe>
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que intentaste

Answer (score 2):

Con este sencillo iframe podremos cargar nuestros documentos para visualizarlos; acepta *Word, Excel, PowerPoint* y *otros documentos asociados* con **Google Docs**.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://upgrade.com.mx/_docs/prueba.doc&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Donde

```
http://upgrade.com.mx/_docs/prueba.doc
```

es la ruta del documento en tu servidor.

Cabe destacar que si el documento está **protegido con contraseña**, no mostrará la vista previa.

Comment: Así es. Con esa  línea que me enseñas lo logro pero el archivo tiene que estar en un servidor previamente montado. Lo que quiero es que se muestre la vista previa de un archivo que el usuario seleccione en su equipo.

Comment: Entiendo... Seguiré buscando para intentar ayudarte.